# Laravel does not validate 'required' validation in select form

Tags: php, laravel, validation, select, eloquent

When I choose the default (selected), the message error for validation does not appear but it redirects me to the form w/o any message and the function does not proceed any further.

***View***

```
  <select class="form-control select2bs4" name="currency" style="width: 100%;">
                                <option selected="selected" value="">Choose</option>
                                <option value="1">ALL</option>
                                <option value="2">Euro</option>
   </select>
```

***Controller***

```
$rules = [
'currency' => 'required'];

$messages = array(
'currency.required' => 'Currency is required'
 );

$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'currency' => 'required'
      ]);
```

**View**

```
      <select class="form-control select2bs4" name="currency" style="width: 100%;">
                            <option selected="selected" value="">Choose</option>
                            <option value="1">ALL</option>
                            <option value="2">Euro</option>
                             @if ($errors->has('currency')) <p class="help-block error">{{ $errors->first('currency') }}</p> @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you add validation with custom message :

```
 $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|max:250',
        ];
    
    $customMessages = [
        'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

view

```
 <span class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('email') ?? null}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
        $request->validate(
            [
                'currency' => 'required',
                
            ],
            [
                'currency.required' => 'currency is required',
            ]
        );
```

**blade view**

```
    <span class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('currency') ?? null}}
    </span>
```